# Try to download blob (audio/webm) but empty file

Tags: javascript, audio, blob, webm, web-mediarecorder

I tried to download the recorded audio file using javascript, which is

0. Check if getUserMedia is supported --> okay
1. Hit play button and trigger Play() function --> okay
2. Hit stop button and trigger Stop() function --> okay
3. Stop() would trigger Download()

`recordedBlobs` seems fine by checking the log (size !=0),

but `var blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: "audio/webm; codecs=opus"});` would return a empty blob.

[Image for console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82ZLj.png)

**Also something weird: I found that `console.log(recordedBlobs.length)` is 0 ?!**  I'm kinda new to javascript, is this normal?

I feel really confused :(
Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Below is my code.

```
<script>
    let mediaRecorder;
    let recordedBlobs;
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      console.log("getUserMedia supported.");
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia(
          {audio: true, video: false}
        )

        // Success callback
        .then(function (stream) {
           mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        })

        // Error callback
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log("The following getUserMedia error occurred: " + err);
        });
    } else {
      console.log("getUserMedia not supported on your browser!");
    }
    
    function handleDataAvailable(event) {
      console.log('handleDataAvailable', event);
      if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
      }
    }

    function Play() {
        console.log("play");
        recordedBlobs = [];
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
        mediaRecorder.start();
        console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
    }    

    function Stop() {
        console.log("stop");
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        downloadVideo();
    }    

    function downloadVideo() {
        console.log('recorded blob:', recordedBlobs);
        var blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: "audio/webm; codecs=opus"}); 
        console.log('new blob:', blob);
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'test.webm';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(() => {
           document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }, 100);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it has something to do with Javascript's asynchronous properties.  So when `stop()` is called, the data is not ready yet.

Therefore, I added a `onstop` listener, and it works!

```js
function Play() {
    recordedBlobs = [];
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
    mediaRecorder.onstop = downloadVideo;  // download when onstop is triggered
    mediaRecorder.start();
}
```

Then, in function `downloadVideo`, I implemented two versions:
(1) download locally
(2) post to server

```js
function downloadVideo() {
    // 1. download locally
    /*const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, { 'type': 'audio/webm; codecs=opus' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'test.webm';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
       document.body.removeChild(a);
       window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 1000);*/
        
    // 2. post audio blob to server
    const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, { 'type': 'audio/webm; codecs=opus' });
    var data = new FormData();
    var youtube_ID = document.getElementById("youtube_ID").innerHTML;
    data.append('file', blob, youtube_ID);
    data.append('youtube_ID', youtube_ID);
    fetch(`/api/get_recording`, {
        method: "POST", 
        body: data,
    });
```

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/stop_event

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Check if it works if the `recordedBlobs` array has only a single element in it.

Comment: From the image, it looks like the `recordedBlobs` array has only a single element (length = 1)